# The programm doesn't show lists in lambda expressions (python v3)

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Good day everyone, I'm a begginer in programming. I wrote a program for my logistics class to count several variables. The program has to output 3 lists. Program is shown below.

```
def average(lst):

    average =[]
    for i in range(3,len(lst)):
        average.append((lst[i-3]+lst[i-2]+lst[i-1])/3)
    lst = lst[3:]
    print(lst)
    error = list(map(lambda l, m: ((l[j] - m[j]) for j in range(len(lst))), lst, average))
    abserror = list(map(lambda t: (abs(t[k]) for k in range(len(lst))), error))
    print(average, error, abserror, sep='\n')

lst = [45.0, 48.0, 42.0, 48.0, 49.0, 54.0, 47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]

average(lst)
```

After running the program I get:

```
[48.0, 49.0, 54.0, 47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]
[45.0, 46.0, 46.333333333333336, 50.333333333333336, 50.0, 50.333333333333336, 47.666666666666664]
[<generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5871F6C8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874F6C8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874F448>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874F948>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874F9C8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FA48>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FAC8>]
[<generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FB48>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FBC8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FC48>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FCC8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FD48>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FDC8>, <generator object average.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000017C5874FE48>]
```

The expected lists to output are:

```
[48.0, 49.0, 54.0, 47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]
[45.0, 46.0, 46.333333333333336, 50.333333333333336, 50.0, 50.333333333333336, 47.666666666666664]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.6666664, -3.333333, 0, -4.33333, -0.6666666]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.6666664, 3.333333, 0 , 4.33333, 0.666666]
```

So the question is how to output 3 lists with numbers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share what is your expected output exactly? Otherwise it takes time for the reader to understand what you're trying to do with `error` and `abserror`

Comment: I have 'lst' with original values. Then starting from 4th value I make a new list 'average' and count 4th value as an average sum of 3 previous ones in 'lst'. After it I create list 'error', where i count values (starting from 4th one) as (lst[i] - average[i]). The last list 'abserror' returns all numbers in 'error' list as absolute values. I added some corrections to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. You are getting list of generators because *map* function is a generator so you are getting back list of generators. Your code also has an issue, you can't see it until you run it. The issue is with passing values to your lambda (l, m). They are the values and not an iterable. So when you call l[j] or m[j] you will get an error, because they are the float values.

```
def average(lst):

    average = []
    for i in range(3, len(lst)):
        average.append((lst[i - 3] + lst[i - 2] + lst[i - 1]) / 3)
    lst = lst[3:]
    print(lst)
    error = [l - m for l, m in zip(lst, average)]
    abserror = [abs(t) for t in error]
    print(average, error, abserror, sep="\n")


lst = [45.0, 48.0, 42.0, 48.0, 49.0, 54.0, 47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]

average(lst)
```

Output

```
[48.0, 49.0, 54.0, 47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]
[45.0, 46.0, 46.333333333333336, 50.333333333333336, 50.0, 50.333333333333336, 47.666666666666664]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.666666666666664, -3.3333333333333357, 0.0, -4.333333333333336, -0.6666666666666643]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.666666666666664, 3.3333333333333357, 0.0, 4.333333333333336, 0.6666666666666643]
```

Comment: Yes. That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not start by trying to figure out what's wrong with your current code but with applying list comprehension instead of mapping for a neater look. It became:

```py
def average(lst):
    average_list =[]
    # Sub list startting from 4th element
    sub_list = lst[3:]
    for i in range(3,len(lst)):
        average_list.append((lst[i-3]+lst[i-2]+lst[i-1])/3)
    error_list = [sub_list[j] - average_list[j] for j in range(len(average_list))]
    abs_error_list = [abs(error_list[j]) for j in range(len(error_list))]
    print(average_list, error_list, abs_error_list, sep='\n')

lst = [45.0,48.0,42.0,48.0,49.0,54.0,47.0, 50.0, 46.0, 47.0]

average(lst)
```

Which outputs:

```
[45.0, 46.0, 46.333333333333336, 50.333333333333336, 50.0, 50.333333333333336, 47.666666666666664]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.666666666666664, -3.3333333333333357, 0.0, -4.333333333333336, -0.6666666666666643]
[3.0, 3.0, 7.666666666666664, 3.3333333333333357, 0.0, 4.333333333333336, 0.6666666666666643]
```

Comment: hm, that's much easier than I wrote. Got your idea. Thanks!